# Reducing HTML semantics of logo graphic

Tags: html, css

[image]
 [**jsFiddle sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/VRXjc/)

I'm looking for the most hipster way to reduce the HTML semantics (css can be big as necessary) this 4 color logo *without using pictures* anything can change in the structure.  Only requirement is that it works in IE8.  I am using selectivr and modernizr so most selector classes and such should work.  Additionally, I'm using less css so if you can write like that too.

```
  <ul class="logo">
    <li class="webBG"></li>
    <li class="designBG"></li>
    <li class="videoBG"></li>
    <li class="audioBG"></li>
  </ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.logo{margin: 0 0 0 10px;padding: 0;list-style-type: none;}
ul.logo li{display: inline-block; width:5px;height:5px; padding:0;margin:0; float:left;}
.designBG{background:#00c8e8}
.videoBG{background:#33cc77}
.webBG{background:#ec8544}
.audioBG{background:#E58}
```

**UPDATE FINAL SOLUTION**

```
#boilerplate > div{
margin-left:10px;

width:20px;
height:5px;

/*cross browser definitions follow..*/
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left,
                        #ec8544 0%, #ec8544 25%,
                        #00c8e8 26%, #00c8e8 50%,
                        #33cc77 51%, #33cc77 75%,
                        #Ee5588 76%, #Ee5588 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left,
                        #ec8544 0%, #ec8544 25%,
                        #00c8e8 26%, #00c8e8 50%,
                        #33cc77 51%, #33cc77 75%,
                        #Ee5588 76%, #Ee5588 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,
                        #ec8544 0%, #ec8544 25%,
                        #00c8e8 26%, #00c8e8 50%,
                        #33cc77 51%, #33cc77 75%,
                        #Ee5588 76%, #Ee5588 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left,
                        #ec8544 0%, #ec8544 25%,
                        #00c8e8 26%, #00c8e8 50%,
                        #33cc77 51%, #33cc77 75%,
                        #Ee5588 76%, #Ee5588 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(left,
                        #ec8544 0%, #ec8544 25%,
                        #00c8e8 26%, #00c8e8 50%,
                        #33cc77 51%, #33cc77 75%,
                        #Ee5588 76%, #Ee5588 100%);
```

}​

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
```

Comment: Do you not like using images?

Comment: Why do you have these requirements?

Comment: the requirements are self proclaimed.  I just like the simplest HTML as possible.

Comment: You like the simplest HTML as possible -> use an image

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa Accually it wasnt  Solution is posted above.

Comment: @DavidThomas yeah I really don't enjoy using image when they arn't necessarily needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

least html possible:

http://jsfiddle.net/VRXjc/7/

1. Create 1 div
2. Use CSS Gradients to make the colors
3. Set Margins, Height and Width to style

HTML:

```
<div id="logo"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#logo{
background: #ec8544; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #ec8544 25%, #00c8e8 25%, #00c8e8 50%, #33cc77 50%, #33cc77 75%, #ee5588 75%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(25%,#ec8544), color-stop(25%,#00c8e8), color-stop(50%,#00c8e8), color-stop(50%,#33cc77), color-stop(75%,#33cc77), color-stop(75%,#ee5588)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #ec8544 25%,#00c8e8 25%,#00c8e8 50%,#33cc77 50%,#33cc77 75%,#ee5588 75%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #ec8544 25%,#00c8e8 25%,#00c8e8 50%,#33cc77 50%,#33cc77 75%,#ee5588 75%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #ec8544 25%,#00c8e8 25%,#00c8e8 50%,#33cc77 50%,#33cc77 75%,#ee5588 75%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(left,  #ec8544 25%,#00c8e8 25%,#00c8e8 50%,#33cc77 50%,#33cc77 75%,#ee5588 75%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ec8544', endColorstr='#ee5588',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
width:20px;
height:5px;
}
```

Comment: You can actually reduce the html by 3 more characters if you name the css element "x" instead of "logo".

Comment: Or you know, just don't use an ID at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use background linear gradients..

**html**

```
<div class="logo"></div>
```

**css**

```
.logo{
    margin-left:10px;

    width:20px;
    height:5px;

    /*cross browser definitions follow..*/
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left,
                            #ec8544 0%, #ec8544 25%,
                            #00c8e8 26%, #00c8e8 50%,
                            #33cc77 51%, #33cc77 75%,
                            #Ee5588 76%, #Ee5588 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left,
                            #ec8544 0%, #ec8544 25%,
                            #00c8e8 26%, #00c8e8 50%,
                            #33cc77 51%, #33cc77 75%,
                            #Ee5588 76%, #Ee5588 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,
                            #ec8544 0%, #ec8544 25%,
                            #00c8e8 26%, #00c8e8 50%,
                            #33cc77 51%, #33cc77 75%,
                            #Ee5588 76%, #Ee5588 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left,
                            #ec8544 0%, #ec8544 25%,
                            #00c8e8 26%, #00c8e8 50%,
                            #33cc77 51%, #33cc77 75%,
                            #Ee5588 76%, #Ee5588 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(left,
                            #ec8544 0%, #ec8544 25%,
                            #00c8e8 26%, #00c8e8 50%,
                            #33cc77 51%, #33cc77 75%,
                            #Ee5588 76%, #Ee5588 100%);
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/yGkhQ/

Comment: it actually doesn't in IE period.  Stop-point gradiants dont work.

Comment: yes .. indeed ... the code above is ie10 only.. filters only allow for start/end colors..

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
  <div id="boilerplate">
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
div#boilerplate{}
div#boilerplate ul{margin: 0 0 0 10px;padding: 0;list-style-type: none;}
div#boilerplate ul li{display: inline-block; width:5px;height:5px; padding:0;margin:0; float:left;}
div#boilerplate ul li:first-child {background:#00c8e8;}
div#boilerplate ul li:nth-child(2) {background:#33cc77;}
div#boilerplate ul li:nth-child(3) {background:#ec8544;}
div#boilerplate ul li:last-child {background:#E58;}
```